# dotnetcore : Cannot access Kerberos ticket. Ensure Kerberos has been initialized with 'kinit'

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I trying to run and aspnet core app, on ubuntu, using vscode. when a run the app, it give me this error:

```
  System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.GetResult[TResult](IEnumerable`1 valueBuffers, Boolean throwOnNullResult)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
ClientConnectionId:d48c3450-07f9-4cac-bc5f-97e7f7efa54a
```

But I not using Integrated authentication, my connection string look like this: `"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=School360Db;User Id=[user];Password=[password];Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"`

I test this on windows and it work!.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you add version of .Net Core you are using? Also version of Ubuntu that is running your code.

Comment: This issues on github looks like similar: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/356 and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22184

Comment: @Afshar .netcore 2.0 and Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: thanks, this issue was helpful. The problem was a was setting Trusted_Connection=True instead of Trusted_Connection=False

Answer (score 19):

as stated by @jcmordan in the comments - set Trusted_Connection=False.

Comment: A little side note: If net core project works on a non-windows machine, kerberos needed.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.

I am using linux OS and Rider IDE,

I solved it by changing my connection string in appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=ExampleDB;User=SA;Password=mypassword;ConnectRetryCount=0;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

}

Try this format.

Comment: I understand you were offering him a solution to authenticate against SQL Auth, but it isn't a practical method; especially, if the organization has AD in place. Op should focus on their tokens, and your solution doesn't fix the problem, but it is a reasonable solution. The issue as I read it, the Kerberos token to access an MS-SQL, which is being used in conjunction with Active Directory, is not initialized correctly. OP should be working on their krb5 and realm configurations not to disrupt their admins' policies and controls. I was stating facts from OWASP and MS.